# CloudFormation Route53 - Update an existing RecordSet

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-route53

I am trying to write a BLUE/GREEN CFT that tears down and rebuilds the EC2 Instances, ELB and Update the Route53 record Alias with this updated DNS name of this ELB.

If the Alias Record DOESNT exist, I'm able to create the Alias Record Set correctly after the EC2 instances are created and the ELB attaches these instances. But If the recordset exists with the old ELB DNS Name, the CFT **is failing** with "Alias RecordSet exists". Naturally - am looking to UPDATE this record with the updated ELB DNS name on running the full CFT. Any suggestions?

```
    "HostRecord" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
    "Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneName" : "REDACTED",
    "Comment" : "Updates the ELB DNS name into Route 54 recordset.",
    "Name" : "REDACTED",
    "Type" : "A",
    "AliasTarget" : {
        "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ESClusterELB" , "DNSName" ] },
        "HostedZoneId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : [ "ESClusterELB" , "CanonicalHostedZoneNameID" ] }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Managing a single resource (such as a RecordSet) from 2 different CloudFormation stacks is not supported.

I have a few recommandations for your use-case:

1. I recommend you manage the record independently from the templates that you're using for blue/green. Once green is created/updated and you want your record to resolve for the green ELB, you can just update the stack that govern the RecordSet, setting it to the appropriate alias.
2. Using the same base as the first suggestion. You could automate this using the SNS notification triggered by CloudFormation when a stack is created/updated. Using this in conjunction with a Lambda you could dynamically update the stack that controls the RecordSet.
3. You could create a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) that solely serve the purpose of updating the record set to the wanted alias.

Comment: 1) Do you imply I do this directly via Console? 3) This looks promising, any examples I could peruse? I did google but couldnt find an approprite resource

Comment: 1) Not directly in the Route53 but rather in a CloudFormation template that's not impacted by blue/green. 3) There's a lot of resource regarding CustomResources but I bet you won't find anything for that particular use case. If I had to do it, I'd create a simple python CustomResource Lambda that takes the necessary input from the ELB as parameters and "UPSERT" the record in Route53 each time it's invoked.

Comment: Thank you. 3) Looks interesting but on googling I noticed this thread. It seems Route53 doesnt like updating a recordset from outside its domain. Is this still an issue? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=148764. This is what  he wrote "If we do this (either through the webUI or on the command line using "aws route53 change-resource-record-sets" with UPSERT as the operation type), CloudFormation will not delete the Route 53 entry in the HostedZone when deleting the stack. If we don't update the recordset, then it gets deleted as expected."

Comment: That's exactly why I suggest you use the solution 1). You can control the domain entirely through a separate CloudFormation stack. Instead of an  "UPSERT" operation you just update the stack (using a parameter input for exemple) and CloudFormation will handle the rest. The best practice is to always control the resource via CloudFormation, that way you avoid the problem exposed on the forum. You can even mix solution 1) and 3) together by automating the update to the stack managing the record.

Comment: Hello - I've been struggling to get an example of Updating a Route53 stack - from the suggestion you gave which I feel is most promising. Is there any snippet/github location you could point me towards that can help me customize my Route53 recordset update scenario?

Comment: hi @DorianMcAllister, how did you resolve this finally?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to revolve around creating two CloudFormation stacks with conflicting resources which cannot coexist.  One way to approach this is to always create the alias records in such a way that they can coexist.

An approach that should allow that is to create a weighted routing type.  Set the weight of the recordset in both stack instances to 1 and set the recordset ID to "blue" or "green" respectively.

Now you should be able to deploy both CFN stacks side by side without conflict.  If the blue stackinstance is active and the green is not, all dns responses will return the blue alias.  When you then activate green, it will create a recordset alongside the blue and should start to take about half of the traffic.  Now if you deactivate the blue stack, green will take over all traffic.

This does mean you need to disable blue to test green in complete isolation, which is perhaps a little inconvenient and may slow down rollback.  You could have a two-phase deployment, where you keep the weights as stack parameters, then once green is deployed with weight=1, redeploy blue with weight=0 to take it out of dns without tearing it down.  If green is bad, you can deactivate it and blue with weight zero should take over.

Weighted routing is only one routing type option, you could also look at multi-value answers, failover or even geolocation.

Answer (score -1):

Just to get creative. You could also set a parameter that sets a condition in your CF that will execute execute different portions for your Route53 For example, having a condition to  of your CF. CREATE, DELETE, IGNORE. Something like that.